# Css video vertical background

Tags: html, css

I'm  making responsive video as background. I want this video to be 100vh in height and automatically cropped in width when the user uses vertical device orientation(phone for example) to preserve aspect ratio.  Also i want to remove the white bars which you see in the picture below. How to do this?

```css
video{
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100vw;
}

@media (pointer:coarse) {
  @media (hover: none), (hover:on-demand) {
    video {
      height:100vh;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<video src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your background-approach works with videos, but you can do this:

```
<video id="video">
<source/>
</video>
```

and

```
#video{
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom:0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

This will result in full-screen video that gets cropped when the parent-container has different ratio.

If you want to use it as background, just use another container with fixed-position for the content. You can find a full example here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp